# Codeigniter looking for "favicon.ico.html" on one server, not others

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, favicon

I have two servers, alpha and beta (as well as my local machine).

Codeigniter is set to use a page extension in the config, of ".html".

On the beta server, when loading a page, I am getting a request for "http://beta.mydomain.co.uk/favicon.ico.html" but this request is not happening on the alpha server or my local machine.

I do not have a favicon set (don't have one yet) and the fact that it is calling for favicon.ico.html doesn't look good either. I'd have thought CI would know not to add .html to the .ico extension?

Basically, why would the beta server look for this and how can I stop it, or at least fix CI to remove the extension from that request?

Comment: check htaccess file on beta server...(root directoy)

Comment: It's the same as on the alpha server

Comment: compare `page source` of both servers and check on which line the  `icon` is included in template. @MrPablo

Comment: That's the thing, it isn't on the page at all. The files are identical and there is no link to a favicon in my code.

Answer (score 0):

The URL helper will append the extension as set in the configuration. When wanting to link to existing content such as your ico, you cannot do so using any of the URL helper functions while having the extension configuration set. Your only solution is to link to this content without the helper.

> This option allows you to add a suffix to all URLs generated by CodeIgniter.
>    For more information please see the user guide: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html - CodeIgniter application/config/config.php